# TextBox to allow only first character as alphabet, second as special character and rest numbers

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I'd like to have a textbox where user are restricted to enter in T-12321 format.

- First character: t or T
- Second character: - or +
- Third or following characters: 0 - 10 (Numbers)

I'm using following code in textbox PreviewTextInput, but wasn't able to achieve my requirement. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
private void txtAdmitDateFrom_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = new Regex(@"[^0-9tT^+^\-^\/]{1}").IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[Tt]` matches either an uppercase `T` or lowercase `t`. Note that the character class alone will match only a single character.

```
@"^[Tt][+-]\d{0,10}$"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dI4uH0/3)

Comment: or `^(?i)t[+-]\d{0,10}$`

Comment: Thanks Avinash for your prompt answer, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. I just replaced the regex by the one you proposed.

Comment: @AshwinMasarkar Where it fails? Did you check the demo link I added. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

I took my time to explain what is wrong with your regex: it is a negated character class that will only match 1 character that is not a digit, not a `t` or `T`, not a `^`, a `-` (you have it escaped in the character class), or `/`. No need to repeat `^`, BTW.

My answer: you can use this (if you want to allow 0 to 10 digits at the end):

```
^(?i)t[-+]\d{0,10}$
```

Or, if you need to just match numbers from `0` to `10`:

```
^(?i)t[-+](?:[0-9]|10)$
```

Code:

```
e.Handled = new Regex(@"^(?i)t[-+]\d{0,10}$").IsMatch(e.Text); // or
e.Handled = new Regex(@"^(?i)t[-+](?:[0-9]|10)$").IsMatch(e.Text);
```

Test:

```
var rgx = new Regex(@"^(?i)t[-+]\d{0,10}$");
var matches = rgx.Matches("T-12321");
rgx = new Regex(@"^(?i)t[-+](?:[0-9]|10)$");
matches = rgx.Matches("T-10");
```

1) [image] 
2) [image]

Comment: Please make sure you have specified correct requirements in the question body, and update if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Normally, your regex works. But in my case, it fails because I'm trying to validate the text of textbox in PreviewTextInput event. Probably, I'm using in wrong event.

Comment: Did you try TextInput rvent: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput(v=vs.110).aspx ? Or OnTextChanged?